Shading only one eye as a strategy to visually measure effect of sunglasses
I am trying to determine the practical effects of sunglasses in both daytime and nighttime scenarios. Specifically, that beyond a certain tint, darker lenses don't help with daytime glare (your pupils start dilating), and that a minimal tint on glasses while driving at nighttime is generally ok (your pupils might be able to dilate further). However, this is hard to perceptually measure with both eyes covered as the initial effect is obvious, but it takes 10s of seconds for my eyes to adjust to the new normal.
Is covering only one eye with the tinted glasses a sufficiently simple experiment with minimal confounding factors to allow someone to compare an uncovered eye to the covered eye? Related, is the consensual light reflex only a temporary effect, or does it stick around after the eyes have adapted?

Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For reasons mentioned in this post and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. See this list of helpful resources. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

It's generally a good idea to not ignore messages like the above from mods.

Fair points all around, sorry to cause annoyance, it was not intended. I was stuck between fairly shallow pages for a general audience and quite dense medical articles when I Googled things before, but I clearly need to try a bit harder to be of relevance to a medical audience, which makes sense. Hopefully I'll have an update soon, thanks for your encouragement.

After talking with an optometrist, her professional opinion was that someone's pupils should always match in dilation, independent of the tint applied to either eye. If they differ, there is likely an issue in another part of the vision pipeline.
A slightly easier test to show this is by lighting up only one eye with a focusable light and taking a picture. For my eyes in a dim room they are 2/3 fully dilated, but after adding focused light both eyes are around 1/3 dilated. I had about 30 seconds of light exposure, which is plenty of time to settle down.


This observation does not align with my internal perception of overlaying a darker lens onto only one eye, in that I perceive very little cross-eye difference of the scene I am viewing after a 30 second adjustment period. Our conclusion was that my photoreceptors and mind were instead compensating for the light difference by varying the "gain" to each eye. Fascinating!
In summary, shading one eye is not an entirely accurate test, since the effect of pupil dilation will not be properly taken into account.

Citing only your own evidence with an N of 1 makes this an anecdote, not evidence. Answers here are required to show credible references supporting their claims of fact. So, for example, you seem to believe the issue revolves entirely around pupil dilation, but you've offered nothing to support that assumption. If that's true then why do most people need brighter light as they age despite the fact that their pupils are just as responsive as they were when they were younger?
